# azimuth calculation in the python (without geolocation lib)

Tags: python, geolocation, geo, bearing, azimuth

How can I calculate `azimuth` without importing [Geodesic](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/code.html)? (or any other kind of lib)

I want to able to have the same below azi1 and azi2 results giving two geolocations as shown.

```
>>> from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
>>> # The geodesic inverse problem
... Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(-41.32, 174.81, 40.96, -5.50)
{'lat1': -41.32,
 'a12': 179.6197069334283,
 's12': 19959679.26735382,
 'lat2': 40.96,
 'azi2': 18.825195123248392,
 'azi1': 161.06766998615882,
 'lon1': 174.81,
 'lon2': -5.5}
```

BASICALLY I'M JUST  ASKING BASIC IMPLEMENTATION OF AZIMUTH IN PYTHON.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Geodesic lib source code and implement your own version inside your code. Or implement the algorithm from scratch.

Comment: The source is high level to me. I'm just asking for a basic implementation of the formula. That's all... Imagine you have a distance problem, you may use various distance libraries, but also you can convert the euclidean formula to python. So I want to able to convert azimuth formula to python.